# For each row of a column 1, find column 2 rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe with 2.1 million records:

```
p_id o_id in 
1    1    1 
1    1    2
1    2    2
1    1    3
```

I want to create two dataframes
One where there is only 1 `o_id` for 1 `in`

```
p_id o_id in 
1    1    1 
1    1    3
```

One where there is more than 1 `o_id` for 1 `in`

```
p_id o_id in 
1    1    2
1    2    2
```

One thing to call out, there can be multiple `in` for one `o_id`, but one `o_id` for one `in`.

How can I create the two dataframes I am expecting?

Comment: You say "but one o_id for one in", but the `in` value `2` has *two* `o_id` values, `1` and `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no duplicated value for `o_id` and `in`, you can get the value counts of `in`. Then find which `in` value appears one time.

```py
indices = (df['in'].value_counts()
           .eq(1).loc[lambda s: s]
           .index)

out1 = df[df['in'].isin(indices)]
out2 = df[~df['in'].isin(indices)]
```

```
$ print(indices)

Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')

$ print(out1)

   p_id  o_id  in
0     1     1   1
3     3     3   3

$ print(out2)

   p_id  o_id  in
1     1     1   2
2     1     2   2
```